# In Rails 3, how to display arbitrary set of tables from large database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I've got a large database of demographic information, normalized into a large set of tables - stuff like graduation rates, dropout rates, etc. for schools, or crime stats for municipalities. I need to create a query tool allowing a user to pull queried data from any arbitrary set of tables, and display the set in a user-friendly fashion. The problem is the differing schema for each table, when most solutions I find for showing data grids require hard-coding column names.

I can of course write some code to take each table, figure out what column names they each have, and generate some HTML to write out each one, but I was hoping there was a method I hadn't thought of.

(EDIT: I should point out in the body and not just the title that I'm using Rails 3 here.

(EDIT 2: In response to Pedro's answer, I'll clarify... the situation is more of a 'let the user pick an arbitrary set of models to show the data for - like rapes, arsons and burglaries for a set of cities within county x.  Its easy to show that, its trying to allow the same interface to pull attendance and dropout rate for schools in school district x.  Hope that clarifies it... thanks for your help!),

Comment: You could add a `ruby-on-rails3` tag as well. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack). There is a [neat demo](http://ransack-demo.herokuapp.com/) that shows what you can do with it. Also, take a look specially at its [advanced mode](http://ransack-demo.herokuapp.com/users/advanced_search).